# Creating PDF using Core Text - what's the meaning of / fix for 'unsupported 'Zapf' version 00020000' error message

Tags: iphone, pdf, core-text

I am using Core Text, in particular CTFramesetter, to create a nice text layout on a PDF. It all works fine, but on the first call I get the following error message on the console:

```
 <Error>: unsupported 'Zapf' version 00020000.
```

No errors on subsequent call.

The error occurs when the attributed string includes a newline (\n), but not when it doesn't.

Code that reproduces the issue is below. I've placed this is a fresh xcode project, just adding the Core Text framework to get it to compile, so I'm fairly confident the issue lies here.

Does anyone know what the error means and how to avoid it?

As noted, the PDF this produces is just fine. Although the code below does nothing fancy, in my app, I make use of centring, indenting, variable line spacing etc. So working around the issue with, say, drawInRect:withFont isn't really an option. (But if I do use drawInRect:withFont: in this context, definitely no error.)

```
- (void) reproduceTheError;
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* filename = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"testPFF.PDF"];

    CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 595.44, 841.68);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filename, paperRect, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // gives a '<Error>: unsupported 'Zapf' version 00020000.' on first call (but not later calls)
    // if the \n is removed from the string, no error
    NSMutableAttributedString* string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Hello World. ‘Smart quotes’ \nWhat's up?"];
    [string autorelease];

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef) string);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState (currentContext);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, CGRectInset(paperRect, 100.0, 100.0));

    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
    // the current transform prior to drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, paperRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CFRelease(frameRef);    
    CFRelease(framesetter);

    CGContextRestoreGState (currentContext);

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigating this as well.  It seems to be a harmless and is present in the simulator and on the device.  The only thing I can think of is that it's referring to the font name, zapf dingbats.  I get the same error upon calling:

```
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

The rest of my code is pretty much the same as yours as I'm using NSMutableAttributedStrings, CTFramesetterRef, CTFrameDraw, etc.  I've not noticed any bugs, memory leaks, or other issues.  As such I am sorely tempted to ignore it and treat it as a mislabelled message.  Perhaps it should be labelled Info instead of Error.  Another thought is to try and create some content using dingbats glyphs and see if there is a problem there.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've not made any more progress on this, but will post again if I find out more. Your post encourages me to hope that it's not me doing something daft, but some minor gremlin in Apple's code.

Comment: Indeed, I've tested and tested and am now moving the same code into production so I can only conclude it's harmless.